# I didn't find BeaconParserEddystone method

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone

I want to use https://github.com/futomi/node-beacon-scanner this library for BeaconParserEddystone method but I couldn't  How can I use this method?

thank you for your helps

Answer (score 0):

Parsing all supported beacon types is automatic.  You can check for an Eddystone UID detection like this:

```
scanner.onadvertisement = (ad) => {
  if (ad.beaconType == "eddystoneUid") {
    console.log("Detected Eddystone Uid: "+JSON.stringify(ad, null, '  '));
  }
};
```